# Using results from a post request in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms, api

I have a very basic question (I'm sure) - I have an Zoho application and I'm using their REST API to recover a single result from a table.

I want to use that result in a javascript variable - the form request is here:

```
<form id="Latest" method="POST" action="https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/my-company-culture/view/PageFeed_Report">
<input type="hidden" name ="authtoken" value="**********************">
<input type="hidden" name ="scope" id="scope" value="creatorapi">
<input type="submit" value="View Records">
</form>
```

I can auto submit the form using this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("Latest").submit();
</script>
```

Which recovers a the result - but I want to assign this result to a javascript variable and use it in a following piece of code (within the same frame).

I am new to this, so please be gentle! Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like Ajax would be your friend.

Comment: I am so much the beginner - I'll try and get @Ashwin-Balamohan 's jQuery code to work for me first.... :-)

Comment: I cannot use Ajax (I believe) - as the server being queried is not in the same domain....

Comment: Well you can not read the result page because of the other domain, but modern day browsers support CORs.

Comment: Sadly Zoho does not support CORs....definately a problem they need to address.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done with jQuery:

```
<form id="Latest"> 
    <input type="hidden" name ="authtoken" value="**********************">
    <input type="hidden" name ="scope" id="scope" value="creatorapi">
    <input type="submit" value="View Records">
</form> 

<div id="result"></div> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#Latest').submit(function(event) {

        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();

        var url = "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/my-company-culture/view/PageFeed_Report";

        // Get some values from elements on the page:
        var $form = $( this );

        var authtokenData = $('#authtoken').attr('value');
        var scopeData = $('#scope').attr('value');

        // Send the data using post
        var posting = $.post( url, 
            { 
                authtoken: authtokenData,
                scope: scopeData
            } 
        );

        // Put the results in a div
        posting.done(function( data ) {

            // empty results div
            $("#result").empty()

            // write POST result to results div
            $("#result").append("<p>" + data + "</p>);

        });             

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help. However - I cannot get the 'data' variable to display. I realise that I will have to parse the XML somehow to extract the single value I require, but was hoping to use document.write(data) to display it first.

I duplicated your code, substituting the correct authtoken into line 2. I have a ‘view records’ button displayed.


(Here is the XML response)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
<records>
<record id='1630350000000085025’>
<column name="LCI">
<value>
<[CDATA[name=85.71&Q1a=1]]>
</value>
</column>
</record>
</records>
</response>

Comment: My pleasure. How do you want the result to look, MarkE?

Comment: I have a page which follows a survey the survey takes an entire html string, decodes the URL, and passes it to some google chart calls. The query should return name onwards, which I would like to substitute in, rather than recover the value from the URL. (Hope this makes sense) - here is an example link... http://www.culturetransform.com/core-values-survey---thank-you.html?name=53.57&Q1a=1&Q1c=6&Q1d=15&Q1e=4&Q1f=5&Q1g=0&Q2a=5&Q2b=23&Q2c=4&Q2d=0&QCount=31&a=67.91&b=66.78&c=53.91&d=57.03&e=72.66&f=57.03&g=65.63&h=62.99

Comment: I can generate a new authtoken easily - the current one is d670dc68ac0f6d7ca389e7b206a25045 Again, thank you so much, you are helping more than I could ever expect.

Comment: I've created a fiddle - here http://jsfiddle.net/gz2LG/ that is returning the following - {"error": "Please use POST request"}, any ideas why this would be? Thank you again for your help....

Comment: I've added a ; next to empty() and a " next to the final </p> in the code....but still cannot get this to work. I believe that the XML return should show in the <div> - but it's not yet.